# How to include a 'provided' dependency in Play! framework 1.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

We are using Play! framework 1.x and it's [dependency management mechanism](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/dependency).

After reading through the documentation and googling around, I still have no clue how (or whether it is even possible) to reference a *provided* dependency from dependencies.yml, where *provided* means that even though the app is dependent on the library for compilation, it should not be included in the app's lib folder because the library is provided at run-time by the environment (application server, Java etc). A common example of such a library is the Java Servlet API, which is included with Tomcat.

See also [Maven's definition](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) of the *provided* scope.

Does anyone know whether this is possible and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I misread your question the first time.  The best way I found to do this kind of thing is to create a deploy script that deletes any excess jar files from the lib folder.  Not particularly pretty, but it did the job.  (In my case, I was pruning libs that I did not use and thereby increase the spin-up time on Google App Engine)